# Is it possible to draw a matrix with SE mark down?

Tags: support, mathjax, editing, formatting

I wanted to know if it possible to draw a matrix with math tags. I googled and also read 'formatting help', but couldn't find any info. I wanted to edit [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14831/what-will-be-minimum-no-of-operation-to-make-whole-matrix-zero-if-one-is-allowed) question. I think its not possible, but I just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's certainly possible, using the standard LaTeX environments:

```
$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
    4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
    7 & 8 & 9
  \end{pmatrix}$
```

yields:

[image]

See [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Matrices_and_arrays) for details and variants.

Comment: wow, it looks so beautiful. +1 and accepted the answer.